# Integrating AWS Authentication to download URL's through StackMob

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, bucket, stackmob

I'm having issues integrating the AWS iOS SDK (authentication specifically) along with download of a simple URL from a bucket.

I'm using StackMob to store my data, and files are managed through AWS in S3 storage. When querying for an object, the link to the S3 object is given.

I have implemented the Anonymous bucket token registration, and it works fine in the demo application, I can see all the buckets as well as the files in the buckets but here's the big question:

How do I authenticate with AWS using the iOS SDK, and use that authentication to download a URL to an object in my bucket that I already have the link to?

Going directly to that link brings up an access denied error. Also, some of the files are private and not distributed, so I do not want to just make the entire bucket public for people to access with the link.

Any suggestions? I think I read somewhere that you can manipulate the URL to include your access key and secret key, but that you should never include that in a binary as it could get stolen, so maybe having it on a private server and pulling that key to temporarily use it?

Any help would be great!
Thanks

Comment: i have a secure bucket set up that I actually append the temporary (1 hour) access to.  It works well for my needs and allows me to keep the bucket locked down outside of viewing it in my app.

That said, I do include the secret in the binary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I contacted Amazon support, and it turns out that what I'm looking to do is currently impossible with the SDK.

The only way to generate a URL is having the bucket name, key, and use the "getPreSignedURL" API call to get a signed link to it.

I'll leave this up, hopefully someone will learn from this and not have to pay $50/month for support for this one question.